# Unable to save a Django Model Object to a varchar datatype field on Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, django

I am trying to update a object field on a legacy Sql Server database and it's not working.

While I was debugging I realized that my problem was only when I was trying to save to a **varchar** data type field. I had no problem to save to **char**, **numeric** or **decimal** data type fields.

Here follows my code:

```
product = Product.objects.get(id=907169)
product.brand = "test_value"
product.save(update_fields=['brand'])
```

In this case the variable **brand** has a **varchar** data type on the database. So, oddly the object doesn't save and still I get no error message.

Any ideas what's going on?

Here is The Product Model. I auto generated this model with [python manage.py inspectdb](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/legacy-databases/#auto-generate-the-models).

```
class Product(models.Model):
    id = models.DecimalField(db_column='Codigo', primary_key=True, max_digits=7, decimal_places=0)
    info = models.CharField(db_column='Descricao', max_length=200)
    group_code = models.DecimalField(db_column='CodGrupo', max_digits=8, decimal_places=0)
    brand = models.CharField(db_column='CodMarca', max_length=10)

    # ... Other fields ... #

    class Meta:
        #managed = False
        db_table = 'Produtos'
```

I am Using: Python 3.6.0, Django 2.0.2, pyodbc 4.0.22, django-pyodbc-azure

Comment: That's odd! What is your Django version? Also please mention the Product model.

Comment: I've updated the question with this info.